# How to remove crankset for SRAM S350

Tags: crankset, sram, advice

I have a [Kona Rove 2020](https://konaworld.com/archive/2020/rove_st.cfm), which is listed as having a [SRAM S350 crankset](https://www.sram.com/en/service/models/fc-s350-1-a1).

My [understanding is this is a self-extracting crankset](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-removal-and-installation-self-extracting) which means the inner `8mm` non-drive side bolt should be loosened/unscrewed counter/anti clockwise.

[image: close up of a SRAM S350 non-drive side crank on a 2020 Kona Rove with an 8mm bolt nested behind a 10mm retaining ring cap]

I verified the `10mm` outer retaining ring is secure, but I cannot get the inner bolt to budge one iota. I've tried putting the bike in many positions to get ideal leverage, but I get no results.

How should this crankset be removed, and what could be the problem removing it?

Comment: Could just be the "problem" is my own weakness

Comment: Try some penetrating oil and an 8mm Allen socket for a ratchet wrench for more leverage and a friendly helper to put a foot on the opposite pedal. It may have been overtightened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use More Force

That's essentially what this boiled down to. I was correct that this is a self-extracting crank and I was performing the steps that should have worked. More force was required.

@JoeK and @Carel were both correct. @JoeK was right that there was indeed a very loud and obvious "snap" when it finally loosened, and @Carel was right in that having a foot on the opposite pedal was helpful.

In the end (don't try this at home) I found more force by reattaching the drive side pedal and using my large `8mm` wrench as the non-drive side "pedal". I leaned against a wall, mounted the bike (at risk to myself), stood on the "pedals", and did what I could to apply force with my body weight. Eventually, things did come loose, but there was a risk of injury when it suddenly gave way. I almost lost my balance and fell. Having a helpful friend would have been better, but I was on day three of struggling with this and impatient.

[image: 8mm wrench placed in crank being used as a pedal for more leverage and force]

Comment: Do the bolt back up to 54Nm on reassembly. That's very tight!

Comment: or apply a longer lever. This is the exact reason I keep an old bent handlebar from an old bike. Unlike a breaker bar for a car the end of the handlebar has a much tighter fit over the end of a hex wrench

Answer (score 3):

There will be some corrosion and probably loctite on the bolt. It will go (loosen) with a snap, so don't hurt yourself.

You can either use a bigger tool (more leverage) making sure you have a good deep fit in the 8mm and someone to hold the bike steady

or warm the area up with a blow torch first at the risk of damaging surface finishes and plastic parts.